# getJSON success handler not being invoked with no sign of errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

Found several other questions with this topic, but they were syntax errors of people closing their AJAX call too early which I don't appear to have done...

Here's my AJAX call in my jqGrid loadComplete:

```
loadComplete : function() {                     
    $.getJSON("getCurrentProject.html", function(results){
        alert(results);
        $(this).jqGrid('setCaption',"Project: " + results);
    });                     

},
```

As you can see, I'm simply calling a URL to get back a currentProject String and set the caption on the jqGrid accordingly.

Trouble is, the success function is never being invoked!  I looked in Firebug and I can see the server responding with the single String value I expect ("default" in this case).

What am I missing here?  Should I just be using get instead of getJSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use `.getJSON()` if you're expecting the response to actually be JSON. In your case you're expecting a string, so try:

```
loadComplete : function() {
    var $this = $(this);               
    $.get("getCurrentProject.html", function(results){
        alert(results);
        $this.jqGrid('setCaption',"Project: " + results);
    },
    "text");
},
```

You may not need the last parameter to `.get()` to set the expected type to "text", but then again maybe you will - if you don't supply it jQuery will make an "intelligent guess" at the response type and it may guess incorrectly.

Note that within your ajax callback `this` will not be the same as in the `loadComplete` function so you need to keep a reference to that in a variable outside the ajax callback, as shown.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance  I was getting lost in the sea of ajax options!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the AJAX lander is returning valid JSON (http://jsonlint.com/) and that there are no syntax errors on the page. getJSON can fail silently if this is the case. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.